# Background image sizes for diferente mobile devices with Phongap

Tags: android, ios, css, cordova, phonegap-build

I am developing an app for iOS and Android using Phonegap.

I want to use a background-image but since all mobile devices have different sizes my background image gets either cut or distorted.

For the splash screen (which is also a fullscreen image) I can define [different images for different devices](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html)

Is there something similar that I can do for my background-image?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that with cordova configuration.

But you can css and media query:

```
#my-app-container {
    @media screen and (max-width: 320) {
        background-image('/iphone4s-background.jpg');
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 420) {
        background-image('/bigger-background.jpg');
    }
    /* others */
}
```

Another way (but not better from my point of view) is to [detect window size in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window), changing then the background image from code (e.g. with jquery).